# Properties not decrypted using Jasypt with Spring5 Java Annotations and JUnit5

Tags: spring, junit5, jasypt

I've created the following example https://github.com/alexandre-senecal/jasypt-spring5-testapp

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:some.properties")
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    static EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncrypt = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        stringEncrypt.setPassword("leiro");
        return new EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(stringEncrypt);
    }

}
```

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(TestConfig.class)
public class DecyptionTest {

    @Value("${city.name}")
    private String cityName;

    @Value("${country.name}")
    private String countryName;

    @Test
    void decrypt() {
        assertEquals("Penguin City", cityName, "Failed to read unencrypted property");
        assertEquals("Antarctica", countryName, "Failed to read encrypted property");
    }

}
```

Yet it fails with

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Failed to read encrypted property ==> expected: <Antarctica> but was: <ENC(zl94ORjq8JUSN/c5xGgVxomrMd5bf9K4)>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
```

Is Spring 5 incompatible with Jasypt or am I missing some configuration?

Comment: It looks a lot simpler if you use [@EnableEncryptableProperties](https://medium.com/@mail2rajeevshukla/hiding-encrypting-database-password-in-the-application-properties-34d59fe104eb)

Comment: @vhoang I got that impression as well. I guess I'll try with Boot. Thanks